# I keep getting zero division error

Tags: python, python-2.7

Write a program that prompts for a file name, then opens that file and reads through the file, looking for lines of the form:
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475
Count these lines and extract the floating point values from each of the lines and compute the average of those values and produce an output

This is my python code

```
# Use the file name mbox-short.txt as the file name
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
inp = fh.read()
count = 0
total = 0
for line in inp:
    if not line.strip().startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    pos = line.find(':')
    num = float(line[pos+1:]) 
    total = float(total + num)
    count = float(count + 1)
print 'Average spam confidence:', float(total/count)
```

I don't really know whats going on because i keep getting a zero division error on line 13(last line of the code)

Comment: `count` is 0 and you cant divide by 0

Comment: Your file seems to be empty or it doesn't contain line starting with `X-DSPAM-Confidence:`

Comment: thanks for your efforts but i realized the problem was from "inp = fh.read()" because the moment i took that line out that's when the codes started working perfectly

Answer (score 1):

What happens when the string `X-DSPAM-Confidence:` is not found?

If your code doesn't find that string then the Count var is always zero, so this is one situation where you would get a division by zero error.

Try checking the value of Count before you calculate at the end...

maybe:

```
If Count>0 print 'Average spam confidence:', float(total/count)
```

(That may not be the correct python syntax, as I have never used python)

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` statement is skipping the rest of the for loop because `line.strip.startwith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:")` always evaluates to false.

Then, `count` is never incremented and thus stays at 0 the whole time, leading to your division by zero error.

Answer (score 0):

i thing its not reading file properly so it wont be entering the for loop

```
fh = open(fname)
inp = fh.read()
```

try  this and check if its entering the for

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
inp = fh.read()
count = 0
total = 0
for line in inp:
  print inp
```

Comment: thanks for your efforts but i realized the problem was from "inp = fh.read()" because the moment i took that line out that's when the codes started working perfectly....Tbh i have no idea why this "inp = fh.read()" was creating the problem.